# What is the word for finishing/doing a dare?

Tags: verbs

Like when there is a "challenge" or a "mission" you can "accomplish" it. What word can you use for a dare. When I dare a person to do something and he does it what does he "do". "dare accomplished"? (I am looking for a better word than accomplished)

Answer (score 3):

As with any commitment, you can ***[honour](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/honour)*** a dare.

> fulfil (an obligation) or keep (an agreement):

Answer (score 3):

In US English there is a phrase **[take a dare](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/take_a_dare#word=take%20a%20dare)** that means

> be dared to do something and attempt it

There are numerous references in literature with this meaning, as the citations behind this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take%20a%20dare,%20take%20the%20dare&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,take%20a%20dare;,c0;.t1;,take%20the%20dare;,c0) reflect. The sense is *to undertake a dare*.

Unfortunately, to some people the phrase also may [mean](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/take_a_dare#word=take%20a%20dare)

> be dared to do something and *not* attempt it [emphasis added]

The ngram also reflects that. The sense is *to put up with [to take it]*.

Context is everything.

Answer (score 2):

I might say that the person has [***completed***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/complete) the dare, in the same way that one might *complete* any other assignment:

> 1 : to bring to an end and especially into a perfected state <*complete* a painting>

Comment: What if i "challenge" you to do something and when you would want to take that challaenge on, does it mean that you "dared" ?

Answer (score 2):

People typically ***"follow through"*** their dares (and threats!)

> [definition](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/follow+through) of the idiomatic phrase:
>   **"follow through (with something)"** and **"follow something through"**:
>
> to complete an activity, doing what was promised.

Comment: I am actually looking for 1 word. And the situation is like, I dare someone and he ........s

Comment: I'm not sure there is a single word but you can use "follow through" and "make good" as launching points for searches.

Answer (score 2):

One accepts a dare when he agrees to undertake a challenge or (more weakly) a mission, so the idea that a dare is ever finished, completed does not make sense.

Comment: Yup, I was going to suggest the same word.  To *accept a dare* shows commitment to the proposed challenge but doesn't imply that ultimate success ensued.  If I specifically needed to state that someone was successful, I'd probably just use *done*.  (Example "I dared Jim to eat a rock and he *did*!")

Answer (score 0):

The answer has to be 'he dared'.

The verb 'to dare' in its original form is used in the sense 'John dared to jump in the lake', meaning that John was brave enough to jump in the lake.

But 'dare' in a different sense, 'I dare you to jump in the lake', meaning 'I challenge you to jump in the lake' has evolved. But it is a different verb, or the same verb used in a different sense. This verb also gives rise to the noun 'a dare'.

So when you dare someone to jump off a high building and they do it, you are using 'dare' in this second sense. And if they do it then they 'dared', in the first meaning of the verb.